# Legend in base R plot changes line centering when both newline character and subscripts are present

Tags: r, plot, legend

I am trying to make a legend that includes both subscripts (e.g., `expression(x[1])`) and a long label that needs to go into a second line. When I include both, the subscripts print correctly but the item with the newline character prints with wide line spacing and is no longer centered on its marker. If I make the figure on an HPC cluster I get a warning: `In text.default(x, y, ...) : font metrics unknown for character 0xa`. If I make the figure on my own machine I get the same behavior but no warning.

Here is an MWE:

```
dev.new()
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

plot(
    NULL, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "",
    main = "Newline only"
)
legend(
    "topleft", bty = "n", pch = 1, col = 1,
    legend = c(
        "x1",
        "Some\ntext"
    )
)

plot(
    NULL, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "",
    main = "Subscript only"
)
legend(
    "topleft", bty = "n", pch = 1, col = 1,
    legend = c(
        expression(x[1]),
        "Some text"
    )
)

plot(
    NULL, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "",
    main = "Includes both"
)
legend(
    "topleft", bty = "n", pch = 1, col = 1,
    legend = c(
        expression(x[1]),
        "Some\ntext"
    )
)
```

How can I get the subscript from "Subscript only" and the line centering on "Some text" from "Newline only"?